# NuGet packages are partially downloaded to the wrong directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

First off, I have the following setup:

- MS Visual Studio 2019
- .Net 5 SDK
- `dotnet --version`: 5.0.405
- `dotnet nuget --version`: 5.11.1.5

This is regarding an Azure Functions project with the following project structure:

```
| MyProject.sln
| NuGet.Config
| Packages
| - Contains (at least should) all downloaded NuGet Packages
| Sources
| - Contains all subprojects
```

The `NuGet.Config` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="Packages" />
  </config>

  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
  </packageSources>

  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>

  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>

  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="1" /> <!-- Using PackageReference -->
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

The default directory for storing the NuGet packages is `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`.
When I don't provide any NuGet.Config file, any NuGet package is placed there.

Using the above config ensures, that the packages are placed in the `\Packages` directory in project folder -> That's fine!

**BUT:**
When I now open Visual Studio 2019 to things happen:

1. **RESTORE**: Downloads 171 Packages and places them where they should be placed
2. **REBUILD PROJECT**: Downloads another 137 Packages and places them in **default** nuget directory

The result of the second step is NOT what I am expecting.

- Am I doing something wrong within the `NuGet.Config` file?
- Is this kind of a bug?
- Or is that the expected behaviour and I am wrong with my expectations?

Comment: You say .NET 5 sdk yet it looks like you have an older version of code as .net core 5 does not use a nuget.config file.

Comment: So? But why is using the cli command `dotnet restore` apparently using that configuration? And what would be the alternative of configuring nuget stuff? My intention is to have all nuget packages for this project placed in the project folder, respectively.

Comment: The standard is to delete that file and let VS download the nuget packages and their names and references will end up as part of your csproj file and when you build your project all dlls end up in your bin folder by default.  If you want to customise this then that would be a different configuration.

Comment: Where they *should* be placed is `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`, as is the default according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section). Placing them in a `packages` folder under the solution root is the old way of doing it. There's a reason they stopped doing that.

Comment: But also according to the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section):

> "**A relative path can be used in project-specific nuget.config files.**"

So there should be the possibilty to use a project-specific configuration...